# Creating an Array of known Dimensions, Type and Length Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm trying to parse an IDX file (which are used to store multi-dimensional data of a few different types).  I have successfully decoded the header which tells you the type of data (Unsigned Byte, Signed Byte, Short, Int, Float or Double), the number of dimensions and the sizes of those dimensions.  However, with this information, I could not think of or find a way to programmatically declare an array with the above parameters.

**Example:**

```
Type type = getDataType(magicBytes);
int numOfDimensions = getNumberOfDimensions(magicBytes);
int[] sizeOfDimensions = getSizeOfDimensions(numOfDimensions, inputStream, data);
//Declare an array of type with numOfDimensions dimensions and sizes of sizeOfDimensions
```

**What I Tried:**

- To declare a one dimensions array of a specified length and type you
  can use `Array.CreateInstance(type, length);` which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474163/creating-array-of-unknown-type-c-sharp/5474177#5474177).  Maybe this could be implemented into a recursive method?
- I also think [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc2e4ft8(v=vs.110).aspx) is useful, however it does not let you set the
  length of each dimension.  However, this `Type t = type.MakeArrayType(numOfDimensions);` will create an array with the correct amount of dimensions and type just not length.

**Question:**

Does anybody know how to programmatically declare an array of specified type, number of dimensions and length in C# or is the best way forward to take what I have and try and resize the array, however I know this is also troublesome with multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of `Array.CreateInstance`:

```
Array.CreateInstance(type, sizeOfDimensions);
```

> Creates a multidimensional Array of the specified Type and dimension
>   lengths, with zero-based indexing. The dimension lengths are specified
>   in an array of 32-bit integers.